# Flutter Bloc Pattern passing more than just state?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was reading that flutter bloc pattern is best for managing state.
I can see the need to separate display and business logic into separate areas.

Trying to learn flutter/dart from ground up.

I building a listview  and each row of individual items that acts as a shopping card.  User can select # of items or flavors of bagels in each row.

first issue is how to display the count of variable _dozen on screen?   I have cubit/bloc sample code working.  Trying to add simple test logic to when use select intervals of 13 bagels it increment a count of 1 bakers = _dozen.  I can see this in debugger works .  But I cannot ( sorry being new ) cannot figure out how to pass the _dozen   variable to my view_page.  Is passing in Bloc on for state management correct?  or do I fall back and try inheritabve widget?

at end of day just want to display at bottom of screen total dozen bagels order.

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

/// {@template counter_cubit}
/// A [Cubit] which manages an [int] as its state.
/// {@endtemplate}
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
  /// {@macro counter_cubit}
  CounterCubit() : super(12);
  int _dozen = 12;

  /// Add 1 to the current state.
  void increment() {
    if (state >= 0) {
      emit(state + 1);
      _dozen = (    state ~/ 13);
       print('dozen:' + '$_dozen');
    }
  }

  /// Subtract 1 from the current state.

  void decrement() {
    if (state > 0) {
      emit(state - 1);
     _dozen = (    state ~/ 13);
      print('dozen:' + '$_dozen');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to keep more than one `int` in your state; one for `count` and one for `dozen`. Make a separate class `CounterState` to represent your state and hold those values so you end up with this code:

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';

class CounterState {
  int count;
  int dozen;

  CounterState(this.count, this.dozen);
}

/// {@template counter_cubit}
/// A [Cubit] which manages an [CounterState] as its state.
/// {@endtemplate}
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  /// {@macro counter_cubit}
  CounterCubit() : super(CounterState(12,1));

  /// Add 1 to the current state.
  void increment() {
    if (state.count >= 0) {
      final int count = state.count + 1;
      emit(CounterState(count, count ~/ 12));
      print('dozen:' + '${state.dozen}');
    }
  }

  /// Subtract 1 from the current state.

  void decrement() {
    if (state.count > 0) {
      final int count = state.count - 1;
      emit(CounterState(count, count ~/ 12));
      print('dozen:' + '${state.dozen}');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your `Widget`s, access this as `state.count` and `state.dozen` instead of just `state`.
This solution can be improved, but it is sufficient to get you going.